# Backbone: Calling Model fetch on a click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

> Note: I am new to backbone js

Right now when page loads Model.fetch() gets called and view gets updated. I want to change to a click of a button.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <button type="button" id="btnMiningInfo" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Mining Info</button>
     <div class="highlight" id="miningInfo"></div>
</div>
```

**View:**

```
var MiningInfoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id:'info',
    class:'table table-hover',
    template:_.template('<table><tbody><tr><td><span>Number Of Blocks</span></td>'+
                   '<td><span><%= blocks %> </span></td>'+
                '</tr></tbody></table>'),
    initialize: function() {
                   //this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
           var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
           this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    } 
});
var miningView = new MiningInfoView({model: miningModel});
miningView.render();
$('#miningInfo').html(miningView.el);
```

Here I have commented out `initialize` function to stop it fetching the model when page loads.

**Model**

```
var MiningModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/getMiningInfo',
    defaults: {
           blocks: "",
        },
    parse: function(resp) {
           return resp;
    }
});
var miningModel = new MiningModel();
miningModel.fetch();

$("#btnMiningInfo").click(function(){
    miningModel.fetch();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just need to remove one of the fetch calls:

```
var miningModel = new MiningModel();

//Remove this fetch
miningModel.fetch();
```

That will fetch the models when that part of the code gets executed. But seems like you want the mining model to fetch on click, which you already have implemented here:

```
$("#btnMiningInfo").click(function(){
    miningModel.fetch();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. How about the code? Does it look good or needs some re-factoring.

Comment: It looks fine so far.